# Call one notebook from another notebook

Tags: python, sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I would like to call one notebook from another notebook in databricks.

lets say I have notebook_main and notebook_variable.

I want to run the notebook_variable from notebook_main and the out of the notebook vairiable I want to pass in the notebook_main.

For example:

In notebook_variable I have defiend one string variable

```
variable = "Select * From {table}"
```

`{table}` this has to become the dynamic variable in the second notebook.

Currently I have hardcode things in the notebook_main but I want to make it dynamic.

```
dbutils.widgets.text("table", "")
table = dbutils.widgets.get("table")
def update_changefeed(df, epochId):
    filtered_df = df.filter(col("_change_type").isin("insert", "update_postimage", "delete"))
    filtered_df.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView("test2")
    dfUpdates = sqlContext.sql("""
        SELECT * from  
        FROM global_temp.test2 """)
```

So with the above `def` Im trying to filter the `df`. Then create the global temp view out of it. Note that now the temp view name is hard coded and I need to pass the {table} name in it which will also need to be pass in the below `select` statement instead of `global_temp.test2` it should be `global_temp.{table}`.

I have two main problem. How can I out put the notebook_variable result in this main nootebook and if the variables will be passed correctly.

My pseudo code:

```
dbutils.widgets.text("table", "")
table = dbutils.widgets.get("table")
query = out put of the notebook
def update_changefeed(df, epochId):
    filtered_df = df.filter(col("_change_type").isin("insert", "update_postimage", "delete"))
    filtered_df.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView(table)
    dfUpdates = sqlContext.sql(query)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable Notebook -

```
table_name = "sample"
dbutils.notebook.exit(table_name)
```

You should pass the resulting variable on 'exit' method to get it in the main notebook.

Main Notebook -

```
table_name = dbutils.notebook.run("your_variable_notebook_path", 3600, {pass parameters if any in dict format})
```

Now, use this `table_name` in your function

(sample parameter - {"id":100001, "name":"Alpha"})

Comment: `{pass parameters if any in dict format}` can you explain this part please?

Comment: If you want to pass any parameter to variable_notebook, you can pass in that dict. eg - consider you are passing database name from main notebook to variable notebook. Then the dict will be {"database_name": "test_db"}. You can use this database_name variable in your variable_notebook by receiving it in dbutils.widgets.get("database_name")